# Broadcast when screenshot is taken in Android 4.0?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Is there any way that I can listen to broadcast when screenshot is taken or picture is inserted to the MediaStore?

Purpose: Feedback app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid not, the framework developers probably didn't think of a use case for this.

The Android developer [documentation has a full list of Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#constants) broadcast by the system.